# South migrations and Mercurial

Tags: python, django

I'm currently testing some complex migrations in different local test Repo's with Mercurial and Django with South.

What I'm trying to find out is;

1. How will Mercurial deals with the merging
2. How will South respond to the merged and/or follow-up files

Conclusion for both cases; ***bad***..

**Problem 1**

Mercurial almost never understands merging models on itself. Even fairly simple adding/removing fields results in a failure of the `Mercurial Resolve` (automatic) resolve method.

**Problem 2**

Migration files can run out of sync or also not resolve well. Resolving it by is not the worst thing in the world, but it introduces big risks with a bigger team worker in Mercurial, with the main reason that new employees might break stuff constantly.

**Problem 3**

Let's say I have 4 simultaneous checkouts in the same model. Now the problem arises that multiple migration-files in the `Appname/migrations/` folder have different migration-numbers, or the same with different merges.

This complexity introduces the `Inconsistent Migration History` problem, showing something like this;

```
InconsistentMigrationHistory: Inconsistent migration history
The following options are available:
    --merge: will just attempt the migration ignoring any potential dependency conflicts.
```

.. followed by a `--merge` that almost never works (stuff like; `DatabaseError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'item_id'; check that column/key exists")`) and is again way to risky to rely on as a fix with many working team-members.

I am wondering if it's maybe wise to exclude the `migrations` folders from the repository with something like;

```
syntax: regexp
^\w+/migrations/.*
```

I am currently pondering of maybe forcing the team members to at least report a change in a Model field to the Lead Developer first.

Besides that I think when let's say a Model will merge like this:

*Original Repo code*

```
class Sea(models.Model):
    world = models.ForeignKey('World')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    is_it_awesome = models.BooleanField(blank = True, verbose_name = 'Is it awesome?!')
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
```

*Team member 1's code (already committed)*

```
class Sea(models.Model):
    world = models.ForeignKey('World')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
```

*Team member 2's code*

```
class Sea(models.Model):
    world = models.ForeignKey('World')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    is_it_awesome = models.BooleanField(blank = True, verbose_name = 'Is it awesome?!')
    belongs_to_country = models.ForeignKey('Country', blank = True, default = None)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
```

So `Team member 1` removed the `it_is_awesome` field, but `Team member 2` kept it and added `belongs_to_country`.

Now `Team member 2` will pull in the new code and sees the clash of `Team member 1`'s code with his. He now needs to choose if to keep the `is_it_awesome` field or not and if to add `belongs_to_country`. So he walks to the Lead Developer and `Team Member 1` to discuss the conflict. Conclusion; `is_it_awesome` indeed needs to go and `belongs_to_country` can be added.

`Team Member 2` will still need to manually tweak the merge if there are different outcomes to the choices Team members and/or the Lead Developer makes.

I am wonder how other people deal with these issues and if my approach will be ok or still introduce problems.

Long story short; can I migrate without the migration folders safely? My other concern is that it might cause problems with the history South keeps in the database too. It would require all Team Member to keep to a certain pattern of Pulling from the Repo, merging/resolving and only then do a new migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TutorialConflict

The only conflicts you will find are when 2 people touch the same code, and it is 100% correct for mercurial to ask you to intervene.

### Problem 2

You should start by reading the South docs: [Part 5: Teams and Workflow](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part5.html)

Make sure that when employees merge their branches into the development/integration branch, that they move their migration to the next highest number if it needs to be run after everything else, otherwise you can run with `--merge` just fine.

### Problem 3

Before developer 2 integrates his branch, he should merge the current development version into his own, and resolve the conflicts. Only when the conflicts are resolved should he merge it back into the development branch.

Alternatively, you have a "Lead Dev" who acts as gatekeeper, and is responsible for pulling features into the integration branch and acting on conflicts.

ALWAYS STORE YOUR MIGRATIONS IN THE REPO. DO NOT EXCLUDE MIGRATIONS. They are code, just like the rest of your code, and you must take migrations into account when merging. Put in the time and effort to maintain them properly and you will be rewarded 10-fold for it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I can make of it. My greatest fear is the differences in the experience levels of the different developers, which my result in the breaking of the repo fairly easy.

Comment: It's a repo that doesn't loose information. If it breaks, you can fix it.